# Django 1.9.13 cannot rename a many to many model AttributeError: 'unicode'

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I am renaming a many to many model, removing it's last 's'

```
class ModelA(models.Model):

class ModelB(models.Model):
    manytomany = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA, through='ManyToManyModels')

class ManyToManyModels(models.Model):
```

to

```
class ModelA(models.Model):

class ModelB(models.Model):
    manytomany = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA, through='ManyToManyModel')

class ManyToManyModel(models.Model):
```

I can create the migration correctly with makemigrations, and it asks me if I renamed the model. But when I migrate I get this error:

```
./manage.py migrate
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 201, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 465, in alter_field
    old_field.remote_field.through._meta.auto_created and
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: Maybe Django migration does not like string assignement to the `through` argument. Did you try defining the through model before and then write `through=ManyToManyModel`?

Comment: It may be that migrations are confused because you are trying to make both changes at once. Try creating a second model called `ManyToManyModel` first, and if the migrations are successful remove the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed this thanks to Selcuk's answer.

So instead doing everything in the same migration I separated it into two migrations.

**First step.**

I create a new M2M with the name I want it to have.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):

class ModelB(models.Model):
    manytomany = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA, through='ManyToManyModels')

class ManyToManyModels(models.Model):

class ManyToManyModel(models.Model):
```

**Second step.**

I edit the through field pointing it to the new M2M model and removing the old M2M.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):

class ModelB(models.Model):
    manytomany = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA, through='ManyToManyModel')

class ManyToManyModel(models.Model):
```